# Image auto change size on diffrent computer

Tags: excel

I have an image and 2 computers.
I inserted the image to the excel file on computer A and committed to SVN, then I opened the same file on computer B and inserted the same image. The result is like this, both images have different sizes.

[image]
Left image was inserted on computer A, right image was inserted on computer B.

When I open the file on computer A, the left image has original size, the right image is not original size and vise versa, when I open the file on computer B, the right image has original size, the right image is not original size.

Both computers is using Microsoft Professional Office 2010.

Comment: Can you please share some more information, such as ***which method you're using to add the image to Excel***? (as there are several.) See also: "[mcve]"

Comment: I used Insert => Picture to insert image to excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways that images can be inserted into an Excel worksheet, and there are a number of things that can affect how the image appears.

On both machines, `Right-click` the image and choose `Size and Properties...` to confirm that these settings are the same on both.

The screenshot (below) is fairly self-explanatory but there's further explanation below it:

[image: screenshot]

If your pictures (on both machines) both have the same:

- **Original Size** (light blue in my screenshot)
- **Height/Width** matching **Original Size** (blue)
- **Scale Height/Width** *(both 100% or both same)* (green)
- **"Relative to Original Picture Size" is *checked*** (brown)
- Numbers are still the same after clicking <kbd>Reset</kbd> (yellow)

...then my next questions are:

- what type of system are both?  (Mac, Windows, etc?)
- which operating system are both?
- what screen resolution are both?
- which regional settings are both? (ie., cm vs inches?  registered country?)

There's got to be at least one (more likely a few) things different between the two machines?

Also, re-copy the image file from the one PC to the other, just to eliminate that as a possible part of the problem.

Are you inserting the image into ***blank*** worksheet?  If not, are they identical?  Re-copy the worksheet from the one PC to the other.

---

There's definitely at least *something* different between the two machines it's just a matter of eliminating possibilities to figure out the difference so as to match them.

Comment: Everything is same except Width and Scale Width (only width not height). Scale width changed from 100% to 116%.

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved if my customer change it back, but my customer don't want to do it because there will be many excel files with many images, they can't go to every single file and change every single image.

Comment: Is one a Windows machine and the other a Macintosh?

Comment: It's windows OS.

Comment: Both computers?

Comment: Yes, both computers.